# bootstrap responsive position and center text with col-6

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm faced two issues

- col-6 center text what should we do in order change to center,need change to row?
- when the size is small, how to set image and text always at bottom

[image]

```html
<div class="container-fluid ">

  <div class="col-md-6 ser-first-grid text-center">

    <img src="https://www.picwallz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/wallpaper-landscap-sunrise-nature-view-hd-photos-famous-on-high-quality-for-pc.jpg" />

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 ser-first-grid text-center">


    <h3>PRODUCT SOURCING</h3>
    <p>We assist clients in sourcing suppliers to meet specific product requirements.</p>


  </div>

</div>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="col-md-6 ser-first-grid text-center">

    <h3>DESIGN DEVELOPMENT</h3>
    <p>MALCORP possesses the capacity to design specific and specialized products to meet the most discerning of customer requirements.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 ser-first-grid text-center">


    <img src="https://www.picwallz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/wallpaper-landscap-sunrise-nature-view-hd-photos-famous-on-high-quality-for-pc.jpg" />

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle out [link](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/7255/)

Use bootstrap flex-order here for responsive ordering of columns.More info [Bootstrap flex-order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order)

Add this class `order-md-1` on second column and `order-md-2` on first column.

As for the centering part, a `text-center` class on column should've worked.

Also you must put your columns inside rows.